# SQL Select only rows that don't have repeated parent and child values, DB2

Tags: sql

I have a table in DB2 that have relation between two entities:

```
Parent    | Child
-------------------
parentId1 | childId1
parentId2 | childId2
parentId3 | childId3
childId1  | grandchildId1
childId2  | grandchildId2
childId3  | grandchildId3
```

And another table with this identifiers linked with other fields like:

```
Identifier | Value
-------------------
parentId1  |  a
parentId1  |  b
childId1   |  a
childId1   |  b
childId1   |  c
parentId2  |  d
childId2   |  e
parentId3  |  f
parentId3  |  g
childId3   |  f
childId3   |  g
```

How do I get all parentId identifiers who does not have the same 'Value' field as its child?

Expected:

```
Identifier 
----------
parentId1
parentId2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Changed expected result and added more information to explain better my problem

Comment: Added grandchild relation, i have already found it on my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct t1.parent
from t1,t2 t2_for_parent
where t1.parent=t2_for_parent.identifier and not exists (
  select 1 from t2 t2_for_child 
  where t1.child=t2_for_child.identifier
   and t2_for_parent.value=t2_for_child.value)
```

Comment: Not working,  with 3 same values for parent and for child returns all values for parent and child

Comment: Okay, I updated the query to exclude any possible child value matches for a given parent value and to remove value from the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you had no duplicates, you could use two `join`s and return the values:

```
select r.*, t2p.value, t2c.value
from relations r join
     table2 t2p
     on t2c.identifier = r.parent join
     table2 t2c
     on t2c.identifier = r.child
where t2p.value <> t2c.value;
```

If you want to handle cases where the identifiers are missing from `table2`, then you can use `left join`s instead of `join`s and take `null` values into account in the `where` clause.

With duplicates, you can test directly for the matching values:

```
select r.*, t2p.value
from relations r left join
     table2 t2p
     on t2c.identifier = r.parent left join
     table2 t2c
     on t2c.identifier = r.child and
        t2c.value = r.value
where t2c.identifier is null;   -- no match
```

Answer (score 0):

For new version of question:

```
WITH ParentChildDiff AS (
    SELECT p.Identifier, c.Value
    FROM table2 p
    JOIN relation r
        ON r.Parent = p.Identifier
    JOIN table2 c
        ON c.Identifier = r.Child
    EXCEPT
    SELECT p.Identifier, p.Value
    FROM table2 p   
)

SELECT DISTINCT p.Identifier
FROM ParentChildDiff p
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'If there is more than one relation'?

Comment: You can have more relations parent-child than one fe. Parent1-Child1a and Parent1-Child1b with different values. So if one or more have the same value then parrent will not show.

Comment: Not working, the relation is one parent-child. And with 3 same values for parent and for child returns all values for parent and child

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and for example in MySql there is `GROUP_CONCAT()` but you can find similar functionality in other databases:

```
select r.parent
from relations r 
inner join identifiers ip on ip.identifier = r.parent
inner join identifiers ic on ic.identifier = r.child
group by r.parent
having   
  group_concat(distinct ip.value order by ip.value)
  <>
  group_concat(distinct ic.value order by ic.value)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ooMtAvv8RTeAPhmtN9RoHD/1).
Results:

```
| parent    |
| --------- |
| parentId1 |
| parentId2 |
```

ForDB2:

```
LISTAGG(distinct ip.value, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ip.value)
<>
LISTAGG(distinct ic.value, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ic.value)
```

Comment: The database is DB2, do you know something similar with it?

Comment: Oops I get this error... A temporary table could not be created because there is no available system temporary table space that has a compatible page size.. seems DB2 restrictions... but thanks!